# String or binary data would be truncated WHERE IN

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am getting SQL Exception:

> String or binary data would be truncated

in SELECT. I read few questions with same title but they were all about inserting. I am SELECTING.

Code is following:

```
List<CategoryName> navigation = await db.Query<CategoryName>().FromSql(
    $"WITH NestedCategories AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Categories
        WHERE Id IN (
            {string.Join(",", products.Select(x =>
                x.Categories.First().CategoryId).Distinct().Select(x => $"'{x}'"))}
        )
        UNION ALL 
            SELECT t.*
            FROM Categories t
            INNER JOIN NestedCategories c On c.ParentId = t.Id
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT c.Id, c.Name, c.ParentId
    FROM NestedCategories c")
.AsNoTracking()
.ToListAsync();
```

If I generate **string.Join** to console and then put SQL command into query window in Management Studio I dont get any error. I get proper results. Issue is obviously in EF CORE that I am passing too many category Ids. Command is to get nesting categories based on Product-Category Id.

EDIT:

```
public class CategoryName
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT 2 - Solution

```
string inClause = string.Join(",", products.Select(x => x.Categories.First().CategoryId).Distinct().Select(x => $"'{x}'"));

List<CategoryName> navigation = new List<CategoryName>();

using (DbCommand command = db.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
     command.CommandText = $"WITH NestedCategories AS (SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE Id IN ({inClause}) UNION ALL SELECT t.* FROM Categories t INNER JOIN NestedCategories c On c.ParentId = t.Id) SELECT DISTINCT c.Id, c.Name, c.ParentId FROM NestedCategories c";

      await db.Database.GetDbConnection().OpenAsync();

      DbDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

      while (await reader.ReadAsync())
          navigation.Add(new CategoryName() { Id = reader.GetInt32(0), Name = reader.GetString(1), ParentId = await reader.IsDBNullAsync(2) ? null : await reader.GetFieldValueAsync<int?>(2) });
}
```

Comment: The error is due to the fields in the SQL Table not matching the db class in c#.  Either the class has more columns that the SQL Table or the data types in the SQL Table and the c# class are not the same.

Comment: Could the `{string.Join(",", products.Select(x => x.Categories.First().CategoryId).Distinct())}` be written as a SELECT in the SQL instead?

Comment: You are missing quotes for each of your strings in `string.Join` Add something like `String.Join(",", list.Select(p => $"'{p}'"`)

Comment: @jdweng it is matching. Andrew: im afraid not. I would have to rewrite a lot of code. schlonzo: I tried that before.

Comment: @user1085907: And then? The error message should disappear then ;-)

Comment: @schlonzo edited code up. Even with $"'{x}'" its not working

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967155/how-do-i-get-visual-studio-2010-to-refresh-my-dataset-after-i-have-updated-the-d

Comment: @jdweng im using code first then database not database first.

Comment: I doubt `FromSql` has string length constraint but not sure at moment, couldnt find implementation details on GitHub. Only refer is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql. I would recommended to create store procedure for it and make use of `join` instead inner query. This will simply your code and better to maintain.

Comment: You are using db.Query<CategoryName> which is a reference to the classes built in the db.Context.

Comment: @jdweng thats correct. I added line builder.Query<CategoryName>(); to DbContext

Comment: So the classes must match the SQL Table fields.  That is why I recommended you do a refresh shown in the link.

Comment: @jdweng I don't understand what I suppose to do by meaning "refresh". EF Core dont have Table Adapter mentioned in link nor .xsd

Comment: Found another way which is working. Old ADO.NET way

Comment: ADO Net is slower than db Context.  The db Context has a mapping (not Adapter) between classes and Table in the DataBase and the refresh updates the mapping when the DataBase changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be very careful when using `FromSql` method with an inline interpolated SQL string.

Normally interpolated strings are resolved to `string` type, but `FromSql` method has overload with `FormattableString` parameter, which allows it to find the placeholders inside the interpolated string and *bind a command parameter* for each of them.

This normally is a functionality. But in your case you want just the joined string with ids to be embedded in the SQL string, while EF creates a parameter for it, so even if there was not a truncation error, the query won't return correct results because it would contain something like `WHERE IN (@param)` and `@param` will contain the comma separated text which will never match.

The simplest fix is to force the other `FromSql` method overload by either putting the SQL in a variable:

```
var sql = $"...";
List<CategoryName> navigation = await db.Query<CategoryName>().FromSql(sql)
    // ...
```

or use cast operator:

```
List<CategoryName> navigation = await db.Query<CategoryName>().FromSql((string)
    $"...")
    // ...
```

A better approach would to create placeholders ({0}, {1}, ...) inside the SQL string and pass values through `params object[] parameters` argument. This way EF Core will bind parameter for each value (e.g. `WHERE IN (@p0, @p1, ...)`) rather than embedded constants:

```
var parameters = products.Select(x => x.Categories.First().CategoryId).Distinct()
    .Cast<object>().ToArray(); // need object[]

var placeholders = string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0, parameters.Length)
    .Select(i = "{" + i + "}"));

var sql =
$"WITH NestedCategories AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Categories
    WHERE Id IN ({placeholders})
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT t.*
        FROM Categories t
        INNER JOIN NestedCategories c On c.ParentId = t.Id
)
SELECT DISTINCT c.Id, c.Name, c.ParentId
FROM NestedCategories c";

var query = db.Query<CategoryName>().FromSql(sql, parameters);
```

Comment: Correct answer. Thanks for info. I will use simple solution cause there is no User interaction. I am just generating feeds and I need all nested categories for each product.